# Python read file by bytes until sequence of bytes

Tags: python, file, png, file-header

How can I read a file in Python byte-by-byte until a specific sequence of bytes is reached?

This must happen all the time with libraries that read specific kinds of files to parse the header, scan for parameters, etc.

As an example: I'm reading through the [PNG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#11IDAT) and see that pixel data starts after the byte sequence `IDAT`.

I can read the file like this:

```
with open('image.png', 'rb') as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != '':
        byte = f.read(1)
```

But since I'm only reading one byte at a time, I can't watch for `IDAT` directly (since I'd only get the `I` but not the other three bytes). I can't read the file by chunks of four bytes because it won't always line up correctly.

I can imagine keeping track of the last four bytes but thought perhaps there was a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't married to the idea of going byte by byte, you can read the data in one long string then split it by occurrences of `IDAT`.

```
with open('image.png', 'rb') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    combined_line = b''.join(lines)
    IDAT_splited = combined_line.split(b'IDAT')[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks! In the last line, why read from index `1` and not `0`?

Comment: because the data is split on "IDAT" the first element would be before it's appearance

Answer (score 0):

Use `mmap` and treat the file like a giant string.

```
import mmap

with open('image.png', 'rb') as f:
    with mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, mmap.PROT_READ) as mf:
        offset = mf.find(b'IDAT')
        if offset == -1:
            raise Exception("IDAT not found")
    f.seek(offset)
```